# show progress bar/ring in windows 8 app while a webpage is loading in webview control

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have the experience of adding  the progress bars and progress rings while calling  async functions . That has been an easy job as it relies on only IsIndeterminate and IsActive properties of progress bar and progress ring respectively .

Now my question is that , how to show a progress bar/ring  in the app while some webpage is loading in the webview control of a windows 8 app .

I am searching for a property or event , that tells the web page in web view  is currently in loading state . If somebody came across such a property , please write it up else if you have any other solutions , please do tell it !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first declare the delegate

```
public delegate void LoadCompletedEventHandler(  object sender,  NavigationEventArgs e);
```

add the following code logically in an area at which event the progress bar/ring must start showing up.

```
ProgressRing1.IsActive = true; //for progress ring
ProgressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true; //for progress bar
```

Add this line  to transfer the control to the event which determines whether the webview control has fully loaded the webpage.

```
WebView1.LoadCompleted += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(WebView1_LoadCompleted);
```

Define the below function to handle what happens when the webpage has been fully loaded ( your aim is to hide the progress bar/ring at this point of time )

```
void WebView1_LoadCompleted(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
//code for hiding progress bar/ring
ProgressRing1.IsActive = false; //for progress ring
ProgressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false; //for progress bar
}
```

For further reference you may check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.loadcompletedeventhandler) page.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able turn busy off in [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) or `Navigated`, with `Navigated` I believe you'd have to compare with the original link as it fires on redirects.

Comment: I guess you are talking about webbrowser control in windows forms .I   think such a control is neither present in windows 8 apps nor there is an alternative .

Comment: Webview has LoadCompleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just a correction, If you are using it for phone, then instead of

```
`new Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(WebView1_LoadCompleted);`
```

the event handler would be

```
`new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(WebView1_LoadCompleted);`
```