# Windows App Progress Bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows

I used a Windows App template to create a webview and load my responsive website within that webView. I tried to use the `ProgressRing` to show the users that the app is loading till the pages are fully loaded. The `ProgressRing` is coming but is not going away. Below is the actual code of my app.

A quick help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

### MainPage.xaml:

```
x:Class="Zify.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Zify"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <WebView Name="webView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="650" Width="400"/>
    <ProgressRing Name="progress" " IsActive="True" Foreground="#FFE74C3A"/>
```

### MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Zify
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            Uri targetUri = new Uri(@"https://zify.com/index.htm");
            webView1.Navigate(targetUri);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>

        // Event handler for the system's DisplaySettingsChanged event.
        // Detect and then compare the height and width of the screen.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Grid.Row="1" to ProgressRing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to transfer the control to the event which determines whether the `Webview` control has fully loaded the webpage.

```
WebView1.LoadCompleted += new Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(WebView1_LoadCompleted);
```

Then stop the `Progress Bar` once it's fully loaded!

```
void WebView1_LoadCompleted(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
 //code for hiding progress bar/ring
 ProgressRing1.IsActive = false; //for progress ring
 ProgressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false; //for progress bar
}
```

Source: [show progress bar/ring in windows 8 app while a webpage is loading in webview control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536933/)